# Could not map property LanguageBranch - table tblBigTable does not contain any columns that map to DbType.String

Tags: episerver, episerver-6-r2

I have recently moved our EPi-project to a new server and keep getting the following message:

*Could not map property LanguageBranch - table tblBigTable does not contain any columns that map to DbType.String*

I've scriptet out the database with all the tables, views, procedures etc, and used sqlcmd to enter data to the databse.
The app is built in .net 4 and the database used is SQL Server 2008 R2.

The front-end of the app works perfectly, although my images are missing.

The EPi site works fine except for the "EDIT MODE".

When we try to enter the edit mode where the tree of data exist we keep getting the above message.

Is there any tips that you guys might share with me?

I actually have no idea how to go on.

Comment: Was it impossible to just use a DB backup file to move to the new server?

Comment: No, the thing is our client have restricted us in their servers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem when generating SQL scripts. Try this solution (change the target to 2005 server):
http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/thread.aspx?id=60826

Comment: Yes, thnx! I've read that post but our app is built in .net 4 and sql server 2008 r2 so it might not work. Although i'm gonna give it a shot and see what happens. Thnx again!